# How to delete a route by its id or something easy to type

Tags: networking

```
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
```

If I want to delete some route from above, I have to type everything: the ip, gateway, netmask and interface.

Is there an easy way to delete a route? I need it all the time and it gets annoying do type everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not knowing which Ubuntu version you are using, but `ip route del` should do the trick.

You also should use `ip route` to list the routes. Then delete the routes as follows.

```
root@host:~# ip route
default via 192.168.122.1 dev ens3 proto dhcp metric 101 
10.0.10.0/24 dev ens10 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.10.209 metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev ens10 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.122.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.47 metric 101 

root@host:~# ip route del 10.0.10.0/24

root@host:~# ip route
default via 192.168.122.1 dev ens3 proto dhcp metric 101 
169.254.0.0/16 dev ens10 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.122.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.47 metric 101
```

If you cannot find the `ip` command, try to install it with `apt-get install iproute2`.